# How to define increment/decrement/etc operator automatically?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, operator-overloading, c++03

I have a bunch of `enum` types, like this:

```
enum Color {COLOR_RED = 0, COLOR_GREEN = 1, COLOR_BLUE = 2, COLOR_NUM};
enum Direction {DIRECTION_FORWARD, DIRECTION_BACKWARD, DIRECTION_NUM};
enum Choice {CHOICE_THIS, CHOICE_THAT, CHOICE_NUM}; // i've just made it up
```

In many places in my code I would like to do a loop over all possible values; I would like it to look like this:

```
for (Color c = COLOR_RED; c != COLOR_NUM; ++c)
{
    ...
}
```

For that, I define `operator++` together with `Color`:

```
enum Color {COLOR_RED = 0, COLOR_GREEN = 1, COLOR_BLUE = 2, COLOR_NUM};

inline Color& operator++(Color& c)
{
    c = static_cast<Color>(c + 1);
    return c;
}
```

I also define postfix `operator++` for people that are used to coding loops with `i++` instead of `++i`:

```
inline Color operator++(Color& c, int)
{
    Color r = c;
    c = static_cast<Color>(c + 1);
    return r;
}
```

I would like to know how to use templates to have the compiler generate these operators without me having to write too much boring code. I have just found [`boost::unit_steppable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#grpd_oprs) that supposedly generates the postfix `operator++` from the prefix one, but it does only half the work: I still have to provide the prefix `operator++` myself.

The following works but is too "powerful" in my opinion:

```
template <class T> T operator++(T x)
{
    return static_cast<T>(x + 1);
}
```

I would like to have the operators defined only for selected `enum`s.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: Are you absolutely bound to C++03?

Comment: @Xeo Yes (have to compile with MS Visual Studio 2005).

Comment: A template like this will get you into a lot of trouble, and not only for `enum Color {red = 1, blue = 42};`.

Comment: @Cicada What do you think is a bad idea: using templates to generate such code, or overloading any operators at all? (you can also format this as an answer, if you explain why)

Comment: Just as an unrelated idea for you: Use `enum Color { COLOR_begin, COLOR_RED = COLOR_begin, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_end };` to increase the loop readability and separate the actual values RED/GREEN/BLUE from the helpers (begin/end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you started, extend as needed:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum Foo { RED, GREEN, BLUE, SIZE };

template< typename T > struct my_enum_is_unit_steppable { enum { value = false }; };

// for each type you want the operator(s) to be enabled, do this:
template<> struct my_enum_is_unit_steppable< Foo > { enum { value = true }; };

// protect the operators with enable_if
template< typename T >
typename std::enable_if< my_enum_is_unit_steppable< T >::value, T >::type
operator++( T value )
{
    return T( value + 1 );
}

int main()
{
    for( Foo foo = RED; foo != SIZE; ++foo ) {}
}
```

Of course, this uses C++11's `std::enable_if`, but Boost has C++03-versions available.

Comment: Note that the equivalent Boost version is either `boost::enable_if<trait<T>, T>`, or `boost::enable_if_c<trait<T>::value, T>`.